# Exit out of datareader before else, in if-else statement

Tags: c#

I would like to find a way to exit out of datareader after the if statement so that I can execute the insert query in else statement. Is there a way to do it?

I am getting the error that dr is still open and hence cannot perform the below query.

```
sVendorDetails.VendorID = insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is the code:

```
public class VendorDetails
{
    int _VendorID;
    string _VendorName;

    public int VendorID
    {
        set { _VendorID = value; }
        get { return _VendorID; }
    }

    public string VendorName
    {
        set { _VendorName = value; }
        get { return _VendorName; }
    }
}

public VendorDetails VendorCheck(string sVendorName)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_GetVendorByVendorName", myConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    cmd.Parameters["@VendorName"].Value = sVendorName;
    VendorDetails sVendorDetails = null;

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                sVendorDetails = new VendorDetails();
                sVendorDetails.VendorID = ((int)dr["VendorID"]);
                sVendorDetails.VendorName = ((string)dr["VendorName"]).ToUpper().Trim();
            }
        } 
        else if (dr.HasRows!= true)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('VendorName:" + sVendorName + " not found. Inserting Vendor details into Vendor and Invoice table.')", true);
            SqlCommand insertcmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertVendorName", myConnection);
            insertcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            insertcmd.Parameters["@VendorName"].Value = sVendorName;
            sVendorDetails = new VendorDetails();
            sVendorDetails.VendorID = insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sVendorDetails.VendorName = sVendorName;
        }

        dr.Close(); 
        return sVendorDetails;

        }
        catch (SqlException err)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("DB usp_GetVendorByVendorName Error: " + err.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This is why you should always use the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement.

Comment: `if (dr.HasRows) { } else if (dr.HasRows!= true) { }` There is no point to the second if block. `if (dr.HasRows) { } else { }` does the exact same thing.

Comment: It's bad to store the connection in a field (all the more if it's static what we dont know). Instead create, open, use and close the connection where you need it. Best by using the `using`-statement.

Comment: You could not have rows but you still have the DataReader open. You need to close it when entering the Not HasRow if block. By the way, adding **MultipleActiveResultSets=True;** to your connection string will allow to use the connection whil the DataReader is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to close/dispose of your DataReader prior to reusing the connection, as it's still being used.

Maybe something like this?

```
var readerHasRows = false;

using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    readerHasRows = dr.HasRows;

    if(readerHasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            sVendorDetails = new VendorDetails();
            sVendorDetails.VendorID = ((int)dr["VendorID"]);
            sVendorDetails.VendorName = ((string)dr["VendorName"]).ToUpper().Trim();
        }
    }
}

if(!readerHasRows)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('VendorName:" + sVendorName + " not found. Inserting Vendor details into Vendor and Invoice table.')", true);
    SqlCommand insertcmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertVendorName", myConnection);
    insertcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar));
    insertcmd.Parameters["@VendorName"].Value = sVendorName;
    sVendorDetails = new VendorDetails();
    VendorDetails.VendorID = insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sVendorDetails.VendorName = sVendorName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would like to mention

1. Your main issue is that you are not closing your `DataReader`. You can use the `using` statement for it
2. You don't need to explicitly open and close the `SqlConnection`. The `SqlCommand` object will do it as needed.
3. You don't need to check with `if (dr.HasRows)` and then check again in `while (dr.Read())`. Also, you don't need to loop to pick up only one row of data.
4. Ideally, I would put the "Fetch" part in a separate function and the "insert" in a separate function, so the functions stay small and reusable.
5. Your pattern is superfluous `if (flag) {TakeAction`();} else if (!flag) {TakeAction2();}`. Every time the code hits the`else`, it will also hit the`if (!flag)`
6. `sVendorDetails.VendorID = insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line looks fishy. If your Stored Procedure returns the `VendorId`, then you should use `ExecuteScalar`. Currently it is just storing `1` in all case since you are presumably inserting one row.
7. Don't discard the original `SqlException` when creating a custom `ApplicationException`. Upstream system might want to know more details than you are passing. Pass it along as the `InnerException`
8. I have also changed some stylistic aspects:

   1. The variable names changed to the more commonly used `camelCase`, instead of the incorrectly used `Hungarian Notation` (`sVendorDetails` instead of `oVendorDetails`)
   2. Brace in K&R style
   3. Used `var` when the right side is a `new` statement
   4. Use Object Initializers instead of creation+assignment

Below is the code

```
public VendorDetails VendorCheck(string vendorName, SqlConnection myConnection) {
    try {
        return GetVendor(vendorName, myConnection) ?? InsertVendor(vendorName, myConnection);
    } catch (SqlException err) {
        throw new ApplicationException("DB usp_GetVendorByVendorName Error: " + err.Message, err);
    }
}

VendorDetails GetVendor(string vendorName, SqlConnection myConnection) {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_GetVendorByVendorName", myConnection)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        cmd.Parameters["@VendorName"].Value = vendorName;

        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('VendorName:" + vendorName + " not found. Inserting Vendor details into Vendor and Invoice table.')", true); // TODO: Does this really belong here!?!?
            if (dr.Read()) {
                return new VendorDetails {
                    VendorID = ((int)dr["VendorID"]),
                    VendorName = ((string)dr["VendorName"]).ToUpper().Trim()
                };
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

VendorDetails InsertVendor(string vendorName, SqlConnection myConnection) {
    using (var insertcmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertVendorName", myConnection)) {
        insertcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        insertcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        insertcmd.Parameters["@VendorName"].Value = vendorName;
        return new VendorDetails {
            VendorID = (int)insertcmd.ExecuteScalar(),
            VendorName = vendorName
        };
    }
}
```